# How are these two statements about entropy at zero temperature mutually compatible?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

- Third law of Thermodynamics states that entropy of a system is zero at 0 Kelvin.
- When universe attains maximum entropy (Heat death), it will also approach 0 K temperature.

Comment: Check out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe The final temperature may not be zero.

Comment: Is there a source for the second statement?

Comment: In addition:  "The entropy of a system approaches a constant value as its temperature approaches absolute zero".https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics .the constant is not defined as zero,

Comment: also, the cosmc microwave backround radiation , close to zero, has an enormous entropy already, https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2020/01/25/entropy-in-the-universe/ , and entropy can only increase or stay constant